# Error 404 en imagen que no carga

Tags: css, web, imagen, scss, error404

Buen día, tengo un problema, estoy probando mi web y para el caso tengo una imagen de portada que la mando a llamar desde el .scss pero a la hora de subir la web la imagen de portada no carga ya que no accede a la dirección que quiero, la web es: https://joansaro.github.io/myWeb-prueba/
la imagen debería ser llamada de https://joansaro.github.io/myWeb-prueba/assets/portada-2.jpg pero en ves de eso la llama de https://joansaro.github.io/assets/portada-2.jpg

Dejo una imagen de referencia de mi estructura y como llamo la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá esta el repositorio con el código:
https://github.com/joansaro/myWeb-prueba

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade el código para que podamos probarlo. [ask] - [tour]

Comment: Revisa bien tu dirección URL de la imagen. Eso es el problema. El código está todo bien, pero la direccion URL en tu CSS no es correcto

Comment: Intente cambiando la url pero igual tengo el mismo error de no lograr acceder a la imagen

Comment: El código debe ir _como texto, con formato_, _en la pregunta_. Como te han dicho, lee [ask].